# Can we run Uno platform app in the server?

Tags: uno-platform

Is it possible to run uno platform app in a way similar to blazor server.
i.e the business logic run in the server and the UI code run in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, not at this point.

The rendering model used by WinUI is dependent on synchronous stacks between the Javascript and WebAssembly. Doing so would require synchronous calls to a remote server, something that Javascript does not allow for good reasons.

An Uno app is similar to a mobile app, for which service calls are used to perform server side business logic, while keeping time/performance sensitive processing locally on the browser/device.